# genfromtxt: numpy.darray, IndexError: too many indices

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I have a csv file, and I try to open with

```
def datetime_from_str(string):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

def main():

    data = genfromtxt(
        csv_name, delimiter=';', skip_header=1, dtype=None,
        names=col_names, converters={'fecha':datetime_from_str}
    )
```

but, when I try to call one column

```
 print type(data), data[:,1]
```

I get this error

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
IndexError: too many indices
```

Comment: It sounds like your `data` array is one-dimensional, so when you try to access `data[:,1]` an error is thrown. Is the delimiter correct? If you print out `data`, does it look right?

Comment: yes, the data look right `[ ('some value', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 22, 15, 5, 3), 1061.932,` ...

Comment: `data` is a 1d structured array - with 'fields'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `data` is a 1d structured array.  Its `dtype` lists the fields, with name taken from your `col_names`.  Show us `data.dtype`.

Assuming the 2nd name is `fetcha` ('date'), then you should be able access those dates with

```
data['fetcha']  # or
data[col_names[1]]
```